# Input button in modal not submitting external form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I have created an inline formset with Django. Once the form is filled out and the user clicks `Submit` I have coded in a Bootstrap modal that pops up a reminder. The footer of the modal contains an HTML input so the external form can be submitted from the modal.

The problem I am having is that the submit buttons does not submit the form so it can be saved to the database and emailed. Is there a way do accomplish this using a modal?

Template:

```
{% extends "reports/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
<font color="green">
          <h4 >Company</h4>
</font>
<h3>Please enter your nightly reports in the form below.</h3>
<br>
<p>If you would like to add a new line to a category, select <font color="blue">add New Line Item</font> under each category.
When finished, click on <strong><font color="gray">Save and Email to Corporate</font></strong> button at the bottom of the form.</h4>
Once the form is sent, the form will refresh with the information you have entered. If you notice an error after you sent the form, edit the error and click the <strong><font color="gray">Save and Email to Corporate</font></strong> button again to update and resend.</p>
<br>
<h5>If you would like a blank form, click <a href="{% url 'reports:storenightlyreports' %}"><font color="green"> here</font>.</a></h5>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}

        <table class="table">
            {{ formset_new.management_form }}
            <div>
            <br><h4><strong>New</strong></h4><br>
            {% include "reports/formsets.html" with formset=formset_new formset_class_name='new' prefix="new" %}
            </div>
        </table>
        <table class="table">
            {{ formset_renewal.management_form }}
            <div>
                <br><h4><strong>Renewals</strong></h4><br>
            {% include "reports/formsets.html" with formset=formset_renewal formset_class_name='renewal' prefix="renewal" %}
            </div>
        </table>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><strong>Submit</strong></button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Before You Submit!!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please review and make sure that all line items are correct and that the <strong>"Check if No New Items"</strong> is checked if there are no new items for that catagory. If all is correct, please select the <strong>Save and Email</strong> button.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email to Corporate">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @freginold Thanks for the edits! This will help me ask better questions in the future. I know us new developers can be annoying but we truly do learn from your feedback.

Comment: @ProfFalken That's what SO is all about -- learning.

Comment: @freginold I figured out the answer to the main question by adding the `id="formset"` attribute to the `<form>` element and then `form= "formset"` attribute to the `<input>` element. Unfortunately I am noticing that refreshing the page is also submitting the form which triggers an email action. New problem, maybe a new question if I cannot figure it out. I will update this question with the answer I found and close it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After researching the HTML input element, I found that you can use the `id` attribute to id the `<form>` element and call the id using the `form` attribute in the `<input>` element that is coded in the Bootstrap Modal. The relevant updated code is below.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="formset" class="form-inline" action="" method="post"> <!--added id="formset" to the form element-->
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}

        <table class="table">
            {{ formset_new.management_form }}
            <div>
            <br><h4><strong>New</strong></h4><br>
            {% include "reports/formsets.html" with formset=formset_new formset_class_name='new' prefix="new" %}
            </div>
        </table>
        <table class="table">
            {{ formset_renewal.management_form }}
            <div>
                <br><h4><strong>Renewals</strong></h4><br>
            {% include "reports/formsets.html" with formset=formset_renewal formset_class_name='renewal' prefix="renewal" %}
            </div>
        </table>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><strong>Submit</strong></button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Before You Submit!!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please review and make sure that all line items are correct and that the <strong>"Check if No New Items"</strong> is checked if there are no new items for that catagory. If all is correct, please select the <strong>Save and Email</strong> button.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" form="formset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email to Corporate"><!--added form id, form="formset" , to input element-->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hopefully this will help others who use SO as a research tool.